# NotificationManager not starting service

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a `NotificationManager` in a listener service and I want to start a service when the positive button is pressed. So far, this is not working and I suspect it might have something to do with contexts.

```
//NotificationManager in GCM listener service

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService
{

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "IP : " + (String) data.get("ip"));

        Intent acceptCryptoService = new Intent(this, CryptoService.class);
        acceptCryptoService.putExtra(StringResources.CRYPTO_ACTION, true);
        PendingIntent acceptPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, acceptCryptoService, 0);

        Intent declineCryptoService = new Intent(this, CryptoService.class);
        declineCryptoService.putExtra(StringResources.CRYPTO_ACTION, false);
        PendingIntent declinePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, declineCryptoService, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Action acceptAction = new NotificationCompat.Action
                .Builder(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float, "Grant", acceptPendingIntent).build();

        NotificationCompat.Action declineAction = new NotificationCompat.Action
                .Builder(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float, "Decline", declinePendingIntent).build();

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New Password Request From " + (String) data.get("ip"))
                .addAction(acceptAction)
                .addAction(declineAction)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float);

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
    }
```

This is CryptoService

```
public class CryptoService extends Service
{
    String TAG = "CryptoService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        boolean acceptCrypto = intent.getBooleanExtra(StringResources.CRYPTO_ACTION, false);
        Log.i(TAG, "accept crypt: " + acceptCrypto); //Not getting called
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {

    }

}
```

I started `CryptoService` in my `MainActivity`. So subsequent `StartService` calls should invoke `onStartCommand`. However, this is not occuring.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to set action in acceptCryptoService  and declineCryptoService  intent.

```
acceptPendingIntent.setAction(StringResources.CRYPTO_ACTION);
declineCryptoService.setAction(StringResources.CRYPTO_ACTION);
```

Comment: Actions are not used with explicit `Intent`s. Also, it would appear that `CRYPTO_ACTION` is the key for an `Intent` extra, not an `Intent` action.